# What type of result should be returned from the service layer?

Tags: c#, architecture, domain-driven-design

Say, for example, that I have a `PostsService` that creates a post:

```
public class PostsService : IPostsService
{
    public bool Create(Post post)
    {
        if(!this.Validate(post))
        {
            return false;
        }

        try
        {
            this.repository.Add(post);
            this.repository.Save();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

The problem with this is that if an exception is thrown during the repository actions, it's swallowed. `Create()` returns `false` and all that the consumer knows is that the `Post` wasn't added, but doesn't know *why*.

Instead, I was think of having a `ServiceResult` class:

```
public class ServiceResult
{
    public bool Success { get; private set; }
    public Exception Exception { get; private set; }
}
```

Would this be a good design? Or do I even need to report these errors to the consumer? Is it sufficient to say "An error occurred while adding the post." and then log the exception inside of the service?

Any other suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think it depends on the scope of *why*. Some failure reasons shouldn't concern the consumer, in my opinion and these should be logged in the service. On the other hand, there are cases when the consumer should be informed of these reasons, so in addition to logging them, you should indicate the cause of the error somehow.

For instance, suppose a very common use case of a user registration service. It's quite likely that you'd have a unique attribute that identifies the user (user handle, email, etc). This uniqueness must be enforced by the service (and probably at a database level too). Now, if the consumer is trying to register a user and it fails because the constrain was violated, the consumer should be notified of this reasons (so it could try some other user handle). Failed validations fall in the same scenario, most of the times.

If there's some kind of internal DB problem on the other hand, the consumer should not be informed of the details (because that's exclusive responsibility of the service; and it's not something the consumer can do anything about anyway).

Considering that, I'd say returning a boolean is insufficient in many cases. So having some kind of `ServiceResult` type doesn't sound like a bad idea. I'm not sure I would include the `Exception` though. But perhaps you can create some kind of ServiceExpection, specific to your service. Sometimes error codes are just fine for this, too.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Do you think returning an list of error *messages* preferable to the actual exceptions?

Comment: @TheCloudlessSky. In my experience, it doesn't make much difference, but that's probably because I generally write the consumer, in Actionscript, and ocassionally the service part in php or sometimes in .NET). So from the consumer point of vief, exceptions are just messages, not real exceptions that I could catch with a try/catch. In any case, I think an important aspect is making these messages specific to your app. This could be a bit more of work, but you're making them part of your API, so they're documented and both ends agree on what kind of errors are to be expected.

Comment: (cont). For instance, some time ago I worked with some Java service that returned every single exception in case of a failure, so I could see, for instance an exception trhown by an Oracle driver indicating that a unique constrain was violated (the one I mentioned in my answer, actually; this was out of lazyness, I guess). I decided not to try and parse this, because that would tie the consumer to some DB driver on the backend, which is non sense. On the other hand, having a message indicating the business specific rule that was violated would have been quite useful to notifiy the end user.

Answer (score 5):

It's a really bad idea to catch all exceptions.  You only catch that which you can reasonably handle. You can't handle all exceptions, so why are you catching it? To prevent a stack trace?

If you don't want your users to see a horrible stack trace, I get that, but you do want it to die and die horribly so that something isn't corrupted.

Let's say that service threw an  OutOfMemoryException, you just caught it, and won't know whether or not your application is leaking memory like a sieve or is improperly allocating large objects.

That's a bad thing.

If you don't want your user to see what was wrong, then you should change your catch to say:

```
catch (Exception e)
{
    //send it to yourself, log it. Just don't swallow it.
    LogErrorAndEmailDevTeam(e); 
    throw new SaveFailedException("We're sorry. \n" + 
    "It's not your fault, but something bad happened.\n\n" + 
    "We've been notified and will fix it as soon as possible.");
}
```

But even better would be to let the application die a horrible death instead of catching that exception so that you know quickly when something goes wrong.

You don't want your application to continue in a corrupted state, but that's what `catch (Exception)` does.  Are you really sure you can handle whatever is thrown?

Comment: Thanks for your input. As I said at the bottom of the OP, I was thinking of already logging the caught exception and then going from there. A couple questions: say I have a unit of work pattern, and commit is called at the end of all of the service's actions, would it be advisable to try/catch the commit on the unit of work or, like you said, let it die a horrible death since this would be an exceptional case? Also, would using `ServiceResult` work with returning *messages* instead like I've mentioned in the other posts? Thanks!

Comment: You forgot to pass the original exception to the constructor of the new exception.

Comment: @Max Nope, that was on purpose.  The DevTeam gets the actual exception when they open their email or are alerted through the log; the user just gets a known exception that contains a friendly error message.

Answer (score 2):

(Disclaimer: In my experience I've worked a lot more with exposing/consuming services between environments, where the built-in functionality in something like WCF isn't always useful and one doesn't always have control over the client consuming the service.)

More and more in my service designs I've moved towards a request/response system.  (Actually, I've made heavy use of the [agatha-rrsl](http://code.google.com/p/agatha-rrsl/) library in this regard.)  In that design, I have a `BaseRequest` object and a `BaseResponse` object, from which all request and response types inherit.

Continuing with what you were thinking, that `ServiceResult` class would serve well as the start of such a `BaseResponse`.  It doesn't necessarily need the actual exception, but a few things I tend to include are:

1. A `bool` indicating success or failure for any request, even one which returns actual results on success.
2. An `IList<>` of custom `Message` objects, which themselves contain a message type of some sort (Info, Warn, Error, etc.) as well as the message text (and perhaps an additional user-friendly message text for UI display needs), stack trace if relevant, etc.

Going further, I also like to include a few things in the `BaseRequest` such as the originating user, host, etc.

The idea is that the service itself should *never* throw a raw exception.  Whoever is consuming the service should always expect to get a valid response, even if that response indicates a failure of some sort.  It should expect some basic information to come back every time and know how to handle that information.

Comment: Thanks for your response. This is sort of the idea that I was going towards (never letting the service throw a raw exception). The request/response system looks pretty neat, but it *may* be too much for my current system. Regardless, I think it's really neat and I'll keep it in mind.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the `ServiceResult` class is a good idea, but I wouldn't include an exception, there are times you want to report errors but you don't want/need to create/throw/catch an exception, instead I would include a collection of error messages or an enum type indicating what went wrong, something like [MembershipCreateStatus](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.web.security.membershipcreatestatus).

Also, don't catch [Exception](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.exception), it can make bugs hard to find.

Comment: Why wouldn't I catch `Exception` if I'm trying literally *catch all exceptions* at this point in the service? I know in some other code, you should catch specific exceptions, but since the service needs to swallow all errors, doesn't this make sense?

Comment: @TheCloudlessSky: Why do you need to swallow all exceptions?

Comment: So that the consumer doesn't have to be littered with try/catch. I like the idea that the consumer doesn't have to worry about exceptions but can handle the error messages accordingly.

Comment: @TheCloudlessSky: I'd recommend to override the OnException method on your controller, or use an ExceptionFilter, so you don't need to try/catch on every action. The problem with swallowing all exceptions is that you are basically saying all error conditions are acceptable, when clearly there are cases you don't want the app to continue running.

Comment: True. I am using Elmah to log all uncaught errors and will be providing some sort of interface for any errors.

Answer (score 2):

Keep in mind that one of the key benefits of a service oriented architecture is decoupling components of the system.  The more the calling layers have to know about the service the more tightly coupled the layers become.  Following this logic it is better to have the calling layer know as little as possible about the error, all it needs to know is that the service call failed.

Does the calling layer *really* need to know why the service failed?  What can it really do about it?  Is it just so you can show a better message to the user?  In this case does the user really care about the detail? It's easy to think the user wants to know more, just because you as the developer does.  But developers should be getting information about error messages from logs, not from end user messages.

Comment: @James - Yeah great point. This is what I've been trying to figure out. Does the consumer *really* care about *why* something failed (other than validation of course...)? So in your mind, would returning a `bool` be sufficient?

Comment: On the other hand giving more information to user speeds up development. The user programmer does not have to call service provider on the phone every time the service disobeys with the question "what did I do wrong this time?"

Comment: @James. I agree about what you say about decoupling. Yet sometimes the user does need to know and more importantly, the developer does need to know what went wrong. I don't mean internal errors in the service (bugs, rare conditions, etc). But common, expected error conditions should be part of the API and documented and notified accordingly. You can't always rely on logs for this (would you ask Facebook to show you their logs so you know whether some request failed because of a problem on their end or because you issued a bad / invalid request and have a bug you that needs fixing?).

Comment: (cont) Failing silently is as bad an idea as it is returning bad / faux error messages or codes (I remember Twitter used to return a 403 http status code which seemed to indicate some problem in authorization, but really was caused by their servers running out of capacity). So again, I think a service should return meaningful error messages/codes and make them part of its API. Just give the level of detail necessary to the consumer.

Comment: I certainly wouldn't recommend failing silently.  I use WCF, in which case a failure is indicated by a Fault exception.  The return value is always left free to use for a normal return value.  If your service communication mechanism doesn't support exceptions then I would agree use a return value that can indicate success/failure - but I don't like this pattern personally.

Comment: (cont) The examples given above where extra error codes are suggested are examples where it's more for the benefit of the developer rather than the user.  If you have control of the service these can all be sorted out using logging,  if you don't have control of the service then maybe there is some justification.  I think a better model in a widely used public service might be to offer a development version to test against, perhaps that does expose logs, or more error codes. But in production code I would always tend to avoid depending on error codes to drive behaviour if possible.

Comment: @James. Fair enough. I don't know much about WCF but if that allows you to use native exceptions and save some work, it could work just fine in many scenarios. Note, however, that this does *increase* coupling between the service and the consumer by making some assumptions that might not always hold true. Most of third parties services that work over the internet (Facebook, Twitter, Flickr, most google apis, etc) include error messages (I mean objects/structures with data about errors, not necessarily just error codes) in their responses.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using WCF, I'd recommend against a `ServiceResult`, or anything similar for dealing with exceptions in a SOA layer.

You should define a `FaultContract` for your method. This would allow consuming code to know about the types of exceptions that can be thrown and handle them accordingly using traditional `try/catch` blocks.

This [StackOverflow question has a full implementation of Fault Contracts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/648084/throwing-generic-faultexception).

You could still have your front-end simply say "An error has occurred", but using a fault contract would allow for better error handling on the UI layer of your code if it becomes needed in the future.

Comment: FWIW - I'm not using WCF. Should I be? This is for an MVC application. I didn't really want to litter my controllers with many try/catch blocks (what I was trying to avoid). Thanks for your input!